# Como capturar os três últimos dígitos de um número em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Existe alguma função do JavaScript que captura a partir do último caractere?

Por exemplo:

```
var n = 200100;
```

Quero obter somente os 3 números a partir do último caractere. No exemplo acima, daria 100.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Se o valor informado for do tipo **inteiro** (númerico), capture o resto da divisão por 1000:

```js
var n = 200100;
console.log(n % 1000);
```

Se não, se o valor for do tipo **string** (não numérico), utilize [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice):

```js
var n = '200100';
console.log(n.slice(-3));
```

Alternativa [não-padrão](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52640271/why-string-prototype-substr-seems-to-be-deprecated/52640366#52640366), utilizando o método [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr):

```js
var n = '200100';
console.log(n.substr(-3));
```

Comment: Dois detalhes sobre o uso do substr, primeiro que o segundo parametro nesse uso especifico (numero negativo) não seria necessário, apenas isso bastaria `n.substr(-3)`. Segundo, o MDN informa que substr() é obsoleto, mas não encontrei nada disso no https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-string.prototype.substr, talvez o MDN esteja errado, então fiquei na duvida. PS: o mod é muito mais eficiente que qualquer outra solução (apesar do resultado variar no motor JS do Firefox), já regex teve a pior performance: https://jsbench.me/zdkrxhpe2w/1 - Node: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PQR7.png

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, a normatização do `String.prototype.substr` encontra-se no [anexo B](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-additional-ecmascript-features-for-web-browsers) da especificação (reservado para _features_ obsoletas, legadas, etc). Então está numa categoria "diferenciada" mesmo: _"This annex describes various legacy features and other characteristics of web browser ECMAScript hosts."_ Confesso que não sabia dessa situação. A MDN poderia ter deixado mais claro, tbh. [Aqui tem mais info, se alguém quiser.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52640366/7445826)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento. Apesar de ser fora de escopo tenho que deixar minha admiração pelo seu posicionamento. Digo a todos que o lerem, temos que questionar e temos que nos questionar sempre, a todo o momento. Só assim que alcançaremos qualidade em nossa produção. Somos a maior comunidade de desenvolvedores em língua portuguesa e devemos romper com o dogma social de sermos perversamente gentis e aceitar tudo apenas por gentileza ou humildade em detrimento da verdade, da lógica e da razão.

Comment: Oi @GuilhermeNascimento, obrigado pelos complementos. De fato o segundo argumento do substr é desnecessário neste caso, vou editar para deixar o código mais limpo. Também estou invertendo a ordem das opções que ofereci para deixar mais claro que o mod é de longe a melhor opção neste caso. Também não sabia dessa obsolescência do substr! Vou pesquisar sobre os motivos disso, porque ele é bem mais prático do que o `String.prototype.substring` em casos como esse.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar uma logica assim para pegar os últimos números

```js
var n = '200100'

var ultimo = n[n.length - 1]
var segundoUltimo = n[n.length - 2]
var terceiroUltimo = n[n.length - 3]

console.log(terceiroUltimo, segundoUltimo, ultimo)
```

Comment: A votação não foi muito favorável, mas a solução é engenhosa e acredito que performática. Claro que no cenário da pergunta é até óbvio fazer `% 1000` ou usar `substr`, como respondido pelo @bfavaretto (que já teve meu up), mas usar índice nesse caso ainda é muito mais sensato que regex (que já considero que beira o erro nesse cenário) ou outros artifícios. Em algumas situações tem aplicabilidade sim (se não fossem sequenciais, por exemplo). O que faltou foi uma explicaçãozinha do que o [ ] em strings faz, valorizaria.

Comment: Gostaria de perguntar as três pessoas que votaram positivo nessa resposta, qual o motivo dos votos já que essa resposta além de impor uma complexidade desnecessária em uma atividade simples, obter o resto de uma divisão, gera um resultado falho caso o a entrada seja menor que 100.

Comment: @AugustoVasques eu votei tendo em vista o comentário do Bacco. O placar estava muito desproporcional (-5 no momento do meu voto), e de fato essa técnica é engenhosa, mesmo não sendo a melhor solução para o caso específico da pergunta.